# php----url redirection

Tags: php

now, i have an input textfield in a form, which used to filled in the url's name. eg:(google).
i want to get when i put the mouse key hover on the google. the url display on the tool bar is my site's internal address. eg:(http://example.com/... ) then click the google. it will go to the google site.

the input textfield is used to fill in some url's name.

Comment: sounds like a spoofing attempt to me.

Comment: nope,it's not a poofing, this is only used to substract my site's outlink

Answer (score 0):

You can't control mouseover/hover effects from PHP. That's a client-side thing. For that you'd need Javascript. Check out `onMouseOver` and the various tooltip modules in jQuery/MooTools. As well, you won't be able to control the URL being displayed in the address bar (that's forbidden by standard browser security measures), and you MAY be able to control what shows up in the status bar, but that's a user-configurable setting (and I personally keep that locked down).